# Scope of variable initialised in an if statment issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

As far as I understand variables initialised inside if statments are scoped to the function but the following code is throwing up `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'seq_name' referenced before assignment` errors

```
def scraper(filename):
    if 'Identified secondary metabolite regions using strictness' in line:
        seq_name = readfile[i + 1].split('_')[0]
    if seq_name in line
```

I have shortend the code to contain only the relavent bits. I am unsure how to fix this error given that my understanding is correct. Please correct me if it is not.

Comment: You indentation is incorrect.

Comment: are you sure the indentation in the line after the if statement is correct?

Comment: it is correct in my IDE, not sure why stackoverflow is not carrying it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of scope is correct. Variables initialized inside `if` blocks are scoped to the enclosing function.

However, it's still possible (as is happening here) to skip the condition in which you assign the variable, and thus never have assigned it at all. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'seq_name' referenced before assignment` is the error message for whenever a variable hasn't been assigned in the current scope yet, *even when it could have been*. You have to account for that possibility in your code - an `else` clause is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: ah okay thank you. How would I use the else clause to sole the issue?

Comment: @Lamma Set the variable to something else in the `else`, so that by the time you get to it, it's definitely been set one way or another.

Comment: Ah okay, it is weird though as there should never be a case where `seq_name`is not being assigned